# How to show the Integer value of a _getch() char in C?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

How can I know the Integer value of Keyboard char I save with _getch();

For example:

```
int key;
key = _getch();

MessageBox(NULL, key, "Some title", MB_OK);
```

But the message box only shows me some unreadeble stuff like "ÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿ"

Is there any way I can know the integer values of the char keys in C / C++?
Or someone knows ALL the keyboard values of the char keys?
Because I can easily compare: `key == 'a'`

But... I want to try an easier way to compare All Keyboard keys without using the `VK_TAB` and that ~

Comment: There is no such language as C / C++. If your question is about C (which your title claims), stick with that in your description and tags.

Comment: "C / C++" means "In C or C++". If you are not going to help, don't comment plz ^_^

Comment: Note: There are keyboard keys without character, and more characters than anyone could remember. (and JBentley is right, say what you want, because the solution will be different)

Comment: @deviantfan OP marked the question( twice ) with c and c++. Code and question are completely valid in both languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `::MessageBox()` function expects an array of characters (a.k.a. a C string).

`MessageBox(NULL, "123", "title", MB_OK)` will work fine.

`MessageBox(NULL, 123 , "title", MB_OK)` will not work.  `"123"` is a string but `123` is an int.  You can use `sprintf()` to convert the integer to a string.

```
int key = _getch();
char msg[128];
sprintf(msg, "_getch() returned %d", key);
MessageBox(NULL, msg, "Some title", MB_OK);
```

Comment: He won't be able to tell what he did incorrectly with just this answer. You need to expand it.

Comment: Converts number to string.

Comment: omg ~ you're so sweet. So much thanks and it works in comparation. Thanks so much <3! At least you answered... not just added a comment like the ones that doesn't help ^^ THANKS!

Comment: I've edited the answer to provide a but of explanation.

Comment: use MessageBoxA instead of MessageBox, if do not know the how this MessageBox is going to behave like MessageBoxA or MessageBoxW

Comment: @MichaelJ Don't worry, I understood it, just didn't realized how to do it. Thanks <3